# Create new column in DF from first value of split()

Tags: python

I am trying to create a new column from an existing one

```
result['details.dealReference'].str.split('-')
```

This returns a list of lists

```
0     [Gen1, ImfcGKceLY]
1     [Gen2, jxoKLGmLKa]
2     [Gen5, XGbTqEJxVh]
3     [Gen5, UNqZFhLLct]
4     [Gen2, OKybhoAxew]
5     [Gen8, TgmOLWHiDr]
```

Doing something like

```
result['details.dealReference'].str.split('-')[0][0]
```

returns the value I want, but only from the first row. Ideally what I want is

```
result['newColumn'] = result['details.dealReference'].str.split('-')<insert magic here>
```

where the new column contains

```
0     Gen1
1     Gen2
2     Gen5
3     Gen5
4     Gen2
5     Gen8
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you after something like `result['whatever'].str.split('-', n=1, expand=True)[0]` ?

Comment: This did exactly what I was after, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a `lambda` that takes the first element of each string:

```
result['newColumn'] = result['details.dealReference'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-', maxsplit=1)[0])
```

or if `result['details.dealReference']` is already a column of lists just:

```
result['newColumn'] = result['details.dealReference'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: I've probably been a bit unclear about the structure of my data. The first example gives me an error (TypeError: 'n' is an invalid keyword argument for this function). If instead I just do str.split('-', 1) I get "TypeError: must be str or None, not int"

Comment: Thanks! First example works now if I remove the n=1 and just do x.split('-', 1). Python 2 vs 3 difference?

Comment: you can use maxsplit=1 instead